# MySQL InnoDB maintaining two relationships between two tables

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

My goal is to have a table called `emails` and a table called `accounts`, with two separate relationships between them.

- A one-to-many relationship from `accounts` to `emails` so that each account may be associated with some number of emails.
- A one-to-one relationship so that each account is associated with exactly one email.

This will allow my users to add multiple email addresses to their accounts, but enforce that one of those emails is set as their "primary" email.

**Attempt 1**

The first thing I tried was the following:

```
emails          accounts
---             ---

id              id
account         email
email
```

There are two foreign keys necessary to make this work:

```
emails ( account ) REFERENCES accounts ( id ) ON DELETE CASCADE
accounts ( id, email ) REFERENCES emails ( account, id )
```

However, since MySQL does not defer foreign key checks, this doesn't work.

**Attempt 2**

I tried to get away from the tables referencing each other, since this messes up foreign keys in MySQL. The second thing that I tried was the following:

```
emails          accounts
---             ---

id              id
account
email
default
```

Only one foreign key is necessary for this:

```
emails ( account ) REFERENCES accounts ( id )
```

But also this index:

```
UNIQUE KEY emails ( account, default )
```

Unfortunately, this isn't truly a one-to-one relationship, but a one-to-zero-or-one relationship: it allows accounts *not* to be associated with a primary email address.

**Attempt 3??**

How else could one solve this problem? I'm not very familiar with triggers... would that be an appropriate solution here? I've never really used them much. I've always thought triggers were messy. But I digress. I'm here asking for opinions from the community because I'm out of ideas, so maybe I need to change my tune on triggers.

Thanks in advance, everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had to use foreign keys, you could make the `accounts.email` FK column nullable.

Leave `accounts.email` NULL when you create a new account, until you add at least one email. Then `UPDATE accounts` when you're ready to set a default email.

In other words, there's no way to do the circular references, except by taking an extra step.

1. Insert to accounts
2. Insert to emails
3. Update accounts to set a default email

But honestly, I hardly ever see MySQL databases using foreign key constraints in real-world applications at companies I've worked at or visited. Partly for the reason of difficulty managing circular references, but even when the references are not circular, foreign keys lead to some inconveniences, like locking behavior.

Comment: That's interesting! I never considered locking... Do such companies just take care of data integrity at the application level?

Comment: As best they can. But inevitably there accumulate a lot of "orphaned" rows of data, if you don't have constraints enforced by the database. Application code is naturally less well-tested than mature RDBMS systems. Also many databases are accessed by more than one application, and the multiple apps aren't always implemented with exactly the same data integrity logic. So data discrepancies occur.

Comment: Interesting! I will have to consider this as a design strategy. Thank you!